# How do I edit my axios post request so that I successfully send a put request?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios, put

As far as I'm aware I should be using an `axios` `.put` request to send an update to my backend/database which is a Django REST framework.

I have been using `.get`, `.post`, and `.delete` successfully by following a guide.

I've been getting conflicting messages from online resources about how to do a .put request successfully.
Some resources say that the url in my path should be something like `'/path/in/urls/:id'` where `id` is the thing I want to update. Other resources have shown that my inputs to `.put` should have an identical format to my `.post`. For my `.post` I've been using the path `'/path/in/urls/` and then the second argument is an object.

For all of these requests the final argument is always a type of token. In the code I use it looks something like: `tokenConfig(getState)`, but this value is equal to, for example:

```
{
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Token 032b2f569037f0125753ef8f67e7774d34a756646ae28cefd54eb1c54bd0b149"
    Content-type: "application/json"
  }
}
```

I need some clarification on what is wrong with my `.put` request. Here is an example of how I do a `.post` request, where `eventdefinition` is what I'm posting:

```
// ADD EVENT DEFINITION
export const addEventDefinition = (eventdefinition) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/eventdefinitions/", eventdefinition, tokenConfig(getState))
    ...
};
```

Here is my attempt where I keep everything the same as with the `.post` method. As you can see it is nearly identical. With this implementation I get a 405 (Method Not Allowed) error:

```
// EDIT EVENT DEFINITION
export const editEventDefinition = (eventdefinition) => (dispatch, getState) => {

  axios
    .put(`/api/eventdefinitions/`, eventdefinition, tokenConfig(getState))
    ...
};
```

I also tried this implementation where instead of passing in a second argument, I pass in the `id` in the url and what I need to edit also in the url. For this implementation I get a 401 (Unauthorized) error:

```
// EDIT EVENT DEFINITION
export const editEventDefinition = (event_id, event_change) => (dispatch, getState) => {

  const event_key = Object.keys(event_change)[0];
  const event_value = event_change[event_key];

  axios
    .put(`/api/eventdefinitions/${event_id}/?${event_key}=${event_value}/`, tokenConfig(getState))
    ...
};
```

More specifically the first error looks like, in all cases:

```
Method Not Allowed: /api/eventdefinitions/
[20/Nov/2020 00:36:13] "PUT /api/eventdefinitions/ HTTP/1.1" 405 40
```

More specifically the second error looks like, for example:

```
Unauthorized: /api/eventdefinitions/4/
[20/Nov/2020 01:03:51] "PUT /api/eventdefinitions/4/?active_for_generation=true/ HTTP/1.1" 401 58
```

Comment: Have you tested everything in Postman to confirm your API is functioning properly for PUT requests? There's also a neat REST extension in VS Code called REST Client. Example of how I am using axios.put in my app: const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/companies/${id}`, company, config);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `PATCH` instead of `PUT`:

- `PATCH` is for partial update, you only send fields which you want to update,
- `PUT` is for full update (all fields).

```
const event_key = Object.keys(event_change)[0];
const event_value = event_change[event_key];
axios.patch(`/api/eventdefinitions/${event_id}/`, {event_key: event_value}, tokenConfig(getState))
```

Please check my article about [CRUD in DRF+React](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/crud-django-rest-framework-react/).

BTW, you don't need to include token config in each request. You can set token in config:

```
import axios from "axios";
export const setAxiosAuthToken = token => {
  if (typeof token !== "undefined" && token) {
    // Apply for every request
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Token " + token;
  } else {
    // Delete auth header
    delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
  }
};
```